# Быстрое комментирование строки

Tags: vim, комментарии

Ищу способ комментировать отдельные строки (однострочные комментарии) в исходных кодах как в визуальном режиме, так и в режиме вставки, при всем этом хотелось бы обойтись простой правкой .vimrc без дополнительных плагинов. Уверен, что это возможно, поэтому прошу указать от чего бы можно было оттолкнуться.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1676632/4827341

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В качестве отправной точки можно поступить, например, следующим образом.

```vim
function! GetCommentStyleByFileType()
  let file_name = buffer_name('%')
  if file_name =~ '\(\.\|_\)vim'
    return ["\"", '']
  elseif file_name =~ '\.\(bat\|cmd\)'
    return ['::', '']
  elseif file_name =~ '\.\(c\|cpp\|cs\|js\|php\)'
    return ['//', '']
  elseif file_name =~ '\.\(ht\|x\)ml$'
    return ['<!--', '-->']
  elseif file_name =~ '\.\(lua\|sql\)'
    return ['--', '']
  elseif file_name =~ '\.\(vb\|vbs\)'
    return ["'", '']
  endif
  return ['#', '']
endfunction
au BufEnter * let b:comment = GetCommentStyleByFileType()
function! CommentLine()
  let stsymbol = b:comment[0]
  let endsymbol = b:comment[1]
  exe ":sil! norm 0i" . stsymbol . "\<Esc>A" . endsymbol . "\<Esc>"
endfunction
function! UnCommentLine()
  let file_name = buffer_name('%')
  let stsymbol = b:comment[0]
  if file_name =~ '\.\(c\|cpp\|cs\|js\|php\)'
    let stsymbol = '\/\/'
  endif
  let endsymbol = b:comment[1]
  exe ":sil! norm :s/^\s*" . stsymbol . "//\<CR>"
  exe ":sil! norm :s/\s*" . endsymbol . "\s*$//\<CR>"
endfunction
exe "set <M-c>=\ec"
nnoremap <M-c> :call CommentLine()<CR>
inoremap <M-c> <Esc>:call CommentLine()<CR>i
vmap     <M-c> :call CommentLine()<CR>
exe "set <M-u>=\eu"
nnoremap <M-u> :call UnCommentLine()<CR>
inoremap <M-u> <Esc>:call UnCommentLine()<CR>i
vmap     <M-u> :call UnCommentLine()<CR>
```

Так, чтобы закомментировать строку нужно нажать `Alt+C`, чтобы снять комментирование со строки - `Alt+U`. Можно забиндить на другое сочетание клавиш, использование `Alt+некая_клавиша` здесь для примера, ровно как и сами функции, - поэкспериментируйте, возможно сделаете нечто удобное и полезное не только для себя.